# why does this code break out of loop?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import math
t=raw_input()
k=[]
a=0
for i in range(0,int(t)):
    s=raw_input()
    b=1
    c=1
    a=int(s)
    if a==0:
        continue
    else:
        d=math.atan(float(1)/b) + math.atan(float(1)/c)
        v=math.atan(float(1)/a)
        print v
        print d
        print float(v)
        print float(d)
        while():
            if float(v)== float(d):
                break
            b=b+1
            c=c+1
            d=math.atan(float(1)/float(b)) + math.atan(float(1)/float(c))
            print d
        k.append(int(b)+int(c))

for i in range(0,int(t)):
    print k[i]
```

as it's very evident `float(v) != float(d)` till `b` becomes 2 and `c` becomes 3.

Comment: how about formatting it as readable code?

Comment: It is interesting that in Python, the code is formally ambiguous unless it *is* readable...

Comment: instead of float(1), just write 1.0 :)

Comment: nice way of explaining your code... NOT !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `while` loop tests on an empty tuple, which evaluates to `False`. Thus, the statements within the `while` loop will never execute:

If you want your `while` loop to run until it encounters a `break` statement, do this:

```
while True:
    if (some_condition):
        break
    else:
        # Do stuff...
```

Comment: if float(v)== float(d):
                break
its this part thats getting executed !!

Comment: True and False are python keywords, not true or false.

Comment: Minor correction: while does not have an "empty condition", there is no such thing in Python. "while ():" tests empty tuple "()" and, yes, empty tuple evaluates to false. Python has the same behavior for "while []:", "while '':", "while 0:", etc.

Answer (score 2):

If is very dangerous to make comparsisons like float(a)==float(b) since float variables have no exact representation. Due to rounding errors you may not have identic values.

Even 2*0.5 may not be equal 1. You may use the following:

```
if abs(float(a)-float(b)) < verySmallValue:
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

> Floating point math is not exact.
>   Simple values like 0.2 cannot be
>   precisely represented using binary
>   floating point numbers, and the
>   limited precision of floating point
>   numbers means that slight changes in
>   the order of operations can change the
>   result. Different compilers and CPU
>   architectures store temporary results
>   at different precisions, so results
>   will differ depending on the details
>   of your environment. If you do a
>   calculation and then compare the
>   results against some expected value it
>   is highly unlikely that you will get
>   exactly the result you intended.   In
>   other words, if you do a calculation
>   and then do this comparison: if
>   (result == expectedResult)
>
> then it is unlikely that the
>   comparison will be true. If the
>   comparison is true then it is probably
>   unstable – tiny changes in the input
>   values, compiler, or CPU may change
>   the result and make the comparison be
>   false.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it didn't reach the break point. The problem is that `while()` does not loop at all. To do an infinite loop, do `while (1):` (since the while condition must evaluate to true. Here's a working (cleaned up) sample.

```
import math
t = raw_input()
k = []
a = 0.0
for i in range(0,int(t)):
    s = float(raw_input())
    b = 1.0
    c = 1.0
    a= float(s)
    if a == 0:
        continue
    else:
        d = math.atan(1.0/b) + math.atan(1.0/c)
        v = math.atan(1.0/a)
        print v
        print d
        while True:
            if v == d:
                print 'bar'
                break
            b += 1
            c += 1
            d = math.atan(1.0/b) + math.atan(1.0/c)
            print d
        k.append(int(b)+int(c))

for i in range(0,int(t)):
    print k[i]
```

Comment: FWIW: "while True" is preferable to "while (1)" in Python.